# Sum from dataGridView's column not calculating the right way in WindowsFormApplication

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I'm struggling to calculate the sums from 3 columns in my dataGridView. The fact is that the function which does this sum is correctly, because on function load where I call the function the first time, it shows the right sum, but if I call it on button that inserts data in gridView, after inserting the data, it shows a totally random number, and I can't understand where is the problem. Thanks !

**Here is the button that inserts and calculats the sum after insert:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                label5.Text = ("1");
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                label5.Text = ("0");
            }
            textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text)).ToString();

            string startPath = Application.StartupPath;


            var filepath = startPath + "\\" + "Grupe.sdf";
            var connString = (@"Data Source=" + filepath);
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var query = "INSERT INTO copii(prezenta, Nume, Prenume, Program, Taxa, Achitat, Diferenta, Grupa) VALUES('" + label5.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox4.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox5.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox6.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox7.Text.Trim() + "')";
                    var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    refresh();
                    sume();   //calling the function for the sum
                    this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Nume"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
                    colorRows();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
```

**Here is the function which calculates the sum from 3 diffent columns of dataGridView:**

```
public void sume()
        {
            int sum1 = 0;
            int sum2 = 0;
            int sum3 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (label17.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    sum1 = Convert.ToInt32(label17.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value));
                    label17.Text = sum1.ToString();
                }
                if (label18.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    sum2 = Convert.ToInt32(label18.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value));
                    label18.Text = sum2.ToString();
                }
                if(label19.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    sum3 = Convert.ToInt32(label19.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value));
                    label19.Text = sum3.ToString();
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }
```

Comment: I believe you are binding datagrid view in refresh() ?

Comment: Yes. That's what refresh does. And after binding, it should calculate the sums again..

Comment: have you checked if after button click when refresh is called data is loaded correctly in datagrid ?

Comment: Sure. Because the refresh function actually creates something like a live insert. On click, it appears instantly in the gridview, so the data is correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sume() method is incorrect, When you are adding values of data grid your method should be like, every time for loop is executed values of sum are reset in your method.so you need to correct it like this(assuming you need to add label 17,18,19 only once).

```
public void sume()
    {
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        int sum3 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (label17.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                sum1 += (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value));                    
            }
            if (label18.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                sum2+= (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value));                    
            }
            if(label19.Text.Length != 0)
            {
               sum3+= (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value));                   
            }
        }

        sum1 += Convert.ToInt32(label17.Text);
        sum2 += Convert.ToInt32(label18.Text);
        sum3 += Convert.ToInt32(label19.Text);
        label17.Text = sum1.ToString();
        label18.Text = sum2.ToString();
        label19.Text = sum3.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("done");
    }
```

and performing summation on datasource is better than performing summation on datagrid.

Comment: Doing the same thing. Calculating wrong. Why? L.E: labels aren't added only once. They are changed each time I insert new  values to the dataBase..

Comment: sum1 **+=**(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value));    adds  (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value)); into previous value of sum (what you obtained in previous iteration of loop) it is equivalent to Sum=Sum+(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value)); whereas    if you use sum3 = Convert.ToInt32(label19.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value)) replaces value of sum in each iteration. So they are diffrent. the random value you are getting is sum of last value in unsortedgrid+labeltext.

Comment: Change them like `sum3 = Convert.ToInt32(label19.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value));` but now they show 0 everytime and anything I do.

Comment: @Ezekiel you can replace your sume() method with the snippet i provided.

Comment: @Ezekiel by adding label once I meant to add label value once to the sum for each insert.

Comment: Got that now. But still.. show the wrong value. Can't get it . Why and how to solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89274/discussion-between-learningnew-and-ezekiel).

Comment: Solved it finally, by giving the label value 0 just before I call sume(); , because it was calculting the latest sum + the newer sum so it showed a total mess. Thank you sir !